# footer doesnt touch bottom and if absolute it hides content?

Tags: html, css

So my footer doesnt touch the bottom of the page. When I set it to position: absolute it does, but then it hides page content and i cant scroll down. can I somehow set the body content to stay above the footer? or force the footer to stay below? ( i didnt include my body in the snippet since its mostly images)

```css
.footer {
 position: relative;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    text-align: center;
 box-shadow: inset 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    /*outline: 2px dashed orange;*/
}
.footerline {
    padding: 80px;
    display: flex;
    font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #D5D5D5;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    /*outline: 2px dashed orange;*/
}
#footerlineshadow {
 color: rgba(240,240,240, 0.9);
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff, 0 0 0 #000, 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
content here
</body>
<footer class="footer">
   <div class="footerline">
     <p id= footerlineshadow>&ltp&gtThis is a Footer&lt/p&gt</p>
      </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: what do you mean footer not touching the bottom , reason could be you dont have much content above the footer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution would be:

- set `.footer` to fixed
- add to body `margin-bottom: x` where x is height of your footer

Answer (score 1):

You should use position:fixed in footer if you do want your footer to remain below as fixed and not scroll at all.
With position:relative, footer will be just below the content and as you have less content, it does not touch the bottom as you have mentioned.

```
.footer:{
  position:fixed;
 }
```